# Is there any way I can only seek 1 message from the old offset?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I would like to know is there any way I can only seek 1 message from the old offset? Since I only want to reprocess 1 message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement `ConsumerSeekAware` and in its:

```
/**
 * When using group management, called when partition assignments change.
 * @param assignments the new assignments and their current offsets.
 * @param callback the callback to perform an initial seek after assignment.
 */
void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback);
```

perform desired `-1` on the required `partition` with its `offset` as a value from that `assignments` map.

Comment: hmm, Artem, what I mean is for example in partition 9, the last committed offset is 200. and I only want to seek the offset 100 and reprocess only this event.  I don't want to reprocess the 101 - 200 .

Comment: Ok. That isn't possible. You only can filter those records

Comment: Ya, I think I need to filter it those :(